# buildbot on windows as a service

Tags: windows, service, buildbot

After following the suggestions outlined [on their website](http://buildbot.net/trac/wiki/RunningBuildbotOnWindows) on how to set up buildbot on windows, I'm left with one last question - I have multiple slaves and one master all set up on one computer (they're all demo slaves right now, doing simple things - later on when we split some of these off to their own machines this won't be quite the same problem), so how do I run them all as services??  I tried adding all my slave/master directories to the service, and I tried running their service set up tool again, to no avail.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, and would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, the advice given on the wiki I linked to was wrong.  They suggest using regedit to add parameters... for some reason multiple build directories can't be specified there.  In buildbot_service.py, it's outlined what should actually be done:

```
#   - Start Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services
#   - Locate the previously installed buildbot service.
#   - Open the "properties" for the service.
#   - Enter the directory names into the "Start Parameters" textbox.  The
#     directory names must be fully qualified, and surrounded in quotes if
#    they include spaces.
#   - Press the "Start"button.
```

Here, multiple directories can be entered, separated by spaces!

Answer (score 0):

A slave can run multiple builds at the same time, so you probably only need one slave on a given machine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I realise this is very old.
Secondly, this is probably more for me than anything.

From the Buildbot documentation on launching a windows service: http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/installation/misc.html#launching-worker-as-windows-service there are instructions for making a registry entry called `parameters` (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\BuildBot\Parameters`) and creating a string entry (`REG_SZ`) with the name `directories` and a value of the absolute path of the base directory for the worker.

For multiple workers (and/or masters) set the value of the `directories` entry to a semi-colon `;` separated list of absolute paths to the respective base directories.